# Authentication in django rest framework with angular

Tags: angularjs, django

Because i have nginx route set, i am using cookies for authentication. The current code that i have in my views for signup are

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def userSignin(request):
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                login(request,form.get_user())
                serializer = userSerializer(user)
                return Response(serializer.data)
        return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_json())
```

My question is what is the right way that i can send output to the user so that it becomes easy for me to handle forms errors output and serializer output. What i had in mind is setting a flag `status` which is a boolean and conditionally parse output, but i am not able to code the same.

Also i would like if someone can guide me to some method so that i replace the `HttpResponse` with DRF `Response` for form errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rest framework itself provide status code of easy usage

if form is valid you can use

`return Response(serializer.data, status=status. HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)`

for more details [www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/)

Comment: What about rejection? status code for that ? couldn't find that in api guide

Comment: you can return response with `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED` and handle the error in angular